# How to fix this 'cmd' not recognized error to carry out the debugging in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

While debugging `cmd is not recognized` is displayed and program is not debugged.

What can be the problem?

I have already checked the `path` and `pythonpath` variables and those seem to be just fine

```
bash
C:\Users\rahul\Desktop\vscode\.vscode>cd c:\Users\rahul\Desktop\vscode\.vscode && 

cmd /C "set "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" && 

set "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" && 

C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe c:\Users\rahul\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.22090\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost
    --port 50265 c:\Users\rahul\Desktop\vscode\.vscode\s.py "
    'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TL;DR: `cmd` is not in your Windows Environment Path.
>   [image]
>   add `%SystemRoot%\system32` to your *System Variables* and restart VSCode.

---

Visual Studio Code has actually brought native support for selecting your terminal, so including cmd into your path is nolonger necessary.

- Press `CTRL + SHIFT + P` -> `Terminal: Select default shell` -> select your terminal.

It will add this line to your settings.json:

`"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"`
should have appeared.

Or if you chose Powershell, it will look like this:

`"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"`

To view your settings.json file, simply:

- `Ctrl + ,` scroll down to `Files: Associations` and click `Edit in settings.json`.

Answer (score 1):

It means that `cmd` is not in your path. Either:

- Add the path to the system or user variables in the control panel
- Use the full path to `cmd` instead (typically `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`), meaning something like:

`cd c:\Users\rahul\Desktop\vscode\.vscode && C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "set "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" && set "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" && C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe c:\Users\rahul\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.22090\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost
--port 50265 c:\Users\rahul\Desktop\vscode\.vscode\s.py "`

Answer (score 1):

If cmd is in your Windows Environment Path, that means that, probably, your default integrated shell is set to wsl bash.
Change it and set
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
in your settings json

You may need to restart VSCode for this to take effect.